# Initializing BitmapImage in background task

Tags: c#, windows-10

My runtime background task is supposed to change the desktop wallpaper image, but when I try to initialize a new BitmapImage I get this exception:

```
System.Exception: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.
```

I've tried doing this:

```
var dispatcher = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;
await dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {

var testBitImg = new BitmapImage();
});
```

But then I get this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: A method was called at an unexpected time
```

I really have no idea what these exceptions mean or how to fix them?

Comment: What do you mean by BackgroundTask - is it a separated process, triggered by system and implementing *IBackgroundTask* or you mean a method run in background on different thread. invoked by Task.Run or other?

Comment: It's a seperate process implementing IBackgroundTask. It is in it's own project that references another shared library that contains the code for initializing BitmapImages, but I get the same errors when trying to initialize them directly in the background task's project.

Comment: You can't access your main app's UI/other elements from *BackgroundTask* - it's a separate process, like an app. Using *CoreApplication* won't help here.

Comment: Ok, but this still doesn't explain the errors when trying initialize a new BitmapImage inside the background task itself?